# All API routes in Next JS do not return any content on the server but working fine locally

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am building a Next JS app. The Next JS version I am using is `^13.4.19`. I have a an API route with the following code (the filepath is `src/pages/api/test.ts`).

```js
const testRoute = async(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "testing",
  });
};

export default testRoute;
```

When I was on accessing the route locally, it was working as expected. Then after I deploy it to the server (I am using Serverless Stack - SST), it does not return any content.
Instead I am just seeing the blank page.

This is the request info

[image]

when I access the route in the postman, I am getting 200 status code. But still empty response/ blank page.

I also tried changing the next js config not to generate Etag like this in next.config.js like this.

```js
api: {
    generateEtags: false,
  },
  generateEtags: false,
```

But it's not working. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: *"not to generate Etag..."* but the `generateEtags` is still `true`. Also, you won't need `res.end();` when you have used `res.json()` earlier. At last, your issue may lie in different problems, including server configs; try to use logs to debug your endpoint.

Comment: I tried all that. Still getting the same error.